# regex only match a word if it's a suffix of a word with more than 1 letter in front

Tags: regex

I have this regex: `wine($|\s|,|;)+` this works fine, however I encountered a problem, namely this will match with `swine` too. Therefore I only want to match it if it's a suffix of a word with at least 2 characters in front of wine, so for illustration it should match words like `trwine, thisiswine, thewine` and thus not things like `swine, this is a swine`
Off course I could do something like this:

```
import re

word = 'wine'
string = 'wine'
pattern = re.compile(".{}($|\s|,|;)+".format(word)) #word as suffix
match = pattern.search(string)
if match:
    if len(match.group(0)) > len(word) + 1:
        print(match)
    else:
        print('no match')
```

But this is so ugly and I'm sure this can be easily done with a regex, but I don't know how.

Comment: Maybe `r"[^\W\d_]{{2,}}{}\b".format(word)`? See https://regex101.com/r/LDkior/1

Comment: Dammn that was fast, yeah seems to work fine. What does the _ mean? @WiktorStribiżew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a regex like

```
pattern = re.compile(r"[^\W\d_]{{2,}}{}\b".format(word))
```

It will look like `[^\W\d_]{2,}wine\b`, see the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LDkior/1/).

**Details**

- `[^\W\d_]{2,}` - 2 or more letters
- `wine`  - `wine` substring
- `\b` - word boundary

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/Z6bY0v):

```
import re
word = 'wine'
s = 'words like trwine, thisiswine, thewine and thus not things like swine, this is a swine'
pattern = re.compile(r"[^\W\d_]{{2,}}{}\b".format(word))
match = pattern.search(s)
if match:
    print(match.group())
else:
    print('no match')
```

Comment: Why to use the _ if it works without the underscore too?

Comment: @CodeNoob `[^\W\d_]` matches a letter. `\w` matches digits, letters and `_`. In Python 2.x, to match any Unicode letter, use `[^\W\d_]` with `re.U` flag. In Python 3, it will match any Unicode letter by default.